# Why TypeScript cannot check property declare if all property optional?

Tags: typescript, axios

I created a reproduct: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-wfqafu?file=src%2Fmain.ts

The core code is as follows:

```js
import Axios from 'axios';
import type { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

interface Params {
  page?: number;
  limit?: number;
}

const req = (
  opts: Omit<AxiosRequestConfig, 'params'> & {
    params: Params;
  }
) => Axios({ url: '/', ...opts });

const query = {
  pag: 2,
  limit: 10,
};

req({ params: query });
```

I think `query` does not match the `Params` interface because `pag` is not longer on the `Params` property, Why does typescript not check for errors in the above code?

If I display the type that defines the query, I can get the correct check:

```js
// Type '{ pag: number; limit: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Params'.
const query: Params = {
  pag: 2,
  limit: 10,
};

req({ params: query });
```

About `AxiosRequestConfig` define [in this](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.27.2/index.d.ts#L75-L113).

Comment: In the code sandbox, params is defined as `{ page?: number }`; which makes `page` optional. But in the question, its visible as a required prop. You just have to fix that

Comment: @boop_the_snoot Thanks for reply, I am sorry that my description is incomplete. I have updated the problem and reproduct link.

Comment: You misspelled "page" as "pag". Is this the issue?

Comment: @tomleb No, I made a mistake on purpose. I want to know why I can work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript does not provide an internal way or utility type for strict type match. So here's something that you can use to make that happen:

```
type StrictMatch<T, S> = T extends S
  ? Exclude<keyof T, keyof S> extends never
    ? T
    : never
  : never;
```

Usage (code simplified for brevity) :

```
interface Params {
  page?: number;
  limit?: number;
}

const req = <T>(opts: { params: StrictMatch<T, Params> }) => {};

const querySuccess = {
  page: 2,
  limit: 10,
};

const queryFails = {
  pag: 2,
  limit: 10,
};

req({ params: querySuccess }); // works flawlessly

req({ params: queryFails }); // Error: Type '{ pag: number; limit: number; }' is not assignable to type 'never'
```